# How can I convert an .img file to .iso?

Tags: iso, convert

I have a `file.img` file that I want to convert to `file.iso`.

The tool `ccd2iso` does not seem to work for this task:

```
Unrecognized sector mode (0) at sector 0!
```

I ensured that the `img` file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 32):

I suggest you to use [`iat`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/iat) (*”Iso9660 Analyzer Tool“*):

First install the package

```
sudo apt install iat
```

You can convert the image using the command

```
iat file.img file.iso
```

In my case, the tool ran for about half a minute (~3GiB image file). The output looked like this:

```
Iso9660 Analyzer Tool v0.1.3 by Salvatore Santagati
Licensed under GPL v2 or later

Detect Signature ISO9660 START at 32768
Detect Signature ISO9660 END at 36864

 Image offset start at 0
 Sector header 0 bit
 Sector ECC 0 bit
 Block 2048
Done
```

According to the man page, the supported formats are (at least) BIN, MDF, PDI, CDI, NRG, B5I, and, of course, ISO-9660.

If iat does not work for your .img file, note that .img files can contain any raw data, which does not necessarily come from a CD/DVD.

### additional info

*Iso9660 Analyzer Tool* is not maintained anymore. It had been published to BerliOS, which is not online anymore. However, here are some working links:

- [archived web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140426100654/http://iat.berlios.de/)
- [archived project page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130421092159/https://developer.berlios.de/projects/iat)
- [inofficial mirror](https://github.com/lolilolicon/iat)
- [latest release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iat.berlios/), officially backuped by [BerliOS+SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/blog/berlios-projects-saved-moving-to-sourceforge-for-distribution/)

a list of **”reference sites“**:

- [iat at Repology](https://repology.org/project/iat/versions)
- [iat at Open Hub](https://www.openhub.net/p/iat)

some links which might be interesting for you if `iat` is *not* what you need:

- [Wikipedia: Comparison of disc image software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disc_image_software)
- [LinuxQuestions.org wiki: CD Image Conversion](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/CD_Image_Conversion)

Comment: I tried to convert the img file, provided in the zip downloaded from [memtest86.com](https://www.memtest86.com/) (with the intention of making it work with [Ventory](https://www.ventoy.net/)), to an iso, and `iat` got locked up at `Detect Signature at 5222476` with 100% CPU and never finished until I killed the process a few minutes later.

Comment: @LonnieBest `.img` files can contain any raw data, not necessarily coming from a CD/DVD. The `memtest86-usb.img` contains a GPT with multiple partitions. You can flash it to your usb storage directly, see the memtest86 docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can install cdemu like that:

- First you add the repository:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cdemu/ppa`
- Update your repo. list:

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Install cdemu:

  `sudo apt-get install gcdemu`

For ddrescue, there is no package existing. You can download it there:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ddrescueview/

Comment: The package for ddrescue is [`gddrescue`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/gddrescue).

Answer (score 1):

Using recent versions of the widely available Iso9660 Analyzer Tool or `iat`:

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y iat
iat --iso -i file.img -o file.iso
```

For help, run `iat --help`. The project site is [here](https://www.berlios.de/software/iso9660-analyzer-tool/).